# Token Session Using tokens to prevent duplicate form submits?

Tags: struts2, token, interceptor

I use Token Session to prevent duplicate form submits, but the first time I make a request to server, I always get error page

```
<action name="show" class="ClientAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession" />
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
    <result name="invalid.token">/WEB-INF/error.jsp</result>
    result type="tiles" name="success">page.view</result>
</action>
```

`"<s:token />"` was added to may success page between `<s:form>` and `</s:form>`, but it doesn't run correctly.

plz help me to solve them, is there another way prevent duplicate form submits. I wait for suggestion, thank u very much. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not using proper interceptor name. If you want to use the session token, it is token-session.

try using token-session instead of tokenSession.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

tag `<s:token />` must be inserted into form which is double-submitted, not into success form. If token tag is missing, interceptor resolve the submitted request as invalid even if it's the first attempt.